# Is it possible to know CRT monitor VGA wires that have no color standards

Tags: vga

Actually I know that rgb wires are thicker than the others also they r coax wires.  But how to  destinguish Vsync and Hsync wires   and the respective ground wire for each signal when the wire colors follow no standard.
Wires are as follow:
Coax pink,white and blue and the others are green,orange,white,yellow brown and pink

Comment: Why do you assume that would be possible?

Comment: If it is the source, look with a scope.  If it is the monitor it may be that the small but theoretically real risk of damage from guessing wrong is worth the experiment since it obviously isn't any use to you without a solution.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no cable coloring standard for VGA.

Also, the outer conductor of each of the color channels **is** the respective color signal ground!

Since the VGA connector is so easy to probe with a multimeter, it should be pretty trivial to figure out the wires yourself, even if we can't help you.